# Summing labels line-section by line in r

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I have a large dataframe of 34,000 rows x 24 columns, each of which contain a category label. I would like to efficiently go through the dataframe and count up *how many* times each label was listed in a *section* of the line, *including 0s*.
(I've used a for loop driving a length(which) statement that wasn't terribly efficient)

Example:

> df.test<-as.data.frame(rbind(c("A", "B", "C","B","A","A"),c("C", "C", "C","C","C","C"), c("A", "B", "B","A","A","A")))
>
> df.res<-as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=6, nrow=3))

Let's say columns 1:3 in df.test are from one dataset, 4:6 from the other. What is the most efficient way to generate df.res to show this:

> A B C A B C
>
> 1 1 1 2 1 0
>
> 0 0 3 0 0 3
>
> 1 2 0 3 0 0

Comment: What have you tried? talking about efficiency without context ( target time ) don't make a lot of sense

Comment: Sorry, I recognize that. I just looked at how long it took to go through the loop, and with a runtime of several hours it's way too slow. @alexis_laz answer below is orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way -using *a lot* of `_apply`s- is the following:

```
#list with the different data frames
df_ls <- sapply(seq(1, ncol(df.test), 3), function(x) df.test[,x:(x+2)], simplify = F)

#count each category
df.res <- do.call(cbind,
   lapply(df_ls, function(df.) { t(apply(df., 1, 
      function(x) { table(factor(unlist(x), levels = c("A", "B", "C"))) })) }))

#> df.res
#     A B C A B C
#[1,] 1 1 1 2 1 0
#[2,] 0 0 3 0 0 3
#[3,] 1 2 0 3 0 0
```

Simulating a dataframe like the one you described:

```
DF <- data.frame(replicate(24, sample(LETTERS[1:3], 34000, T)), stringsAsFactors = F)
#> head(DF)
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24
#1  B  C  C  C  B  A  C  B  B   A   C   C   B   C   B   B   B   C   B   C   C   B   B   C
#2  C  B  C  A  B  C  B  C  A   B   A   C   B   B   A   A   C   A   B   B   B   C   A   B
#3  B  C  C  A  A  A  C  A  C   A   A   A   B   B   A   A   A   C   B   B   A   C   C   C
#4  C  C  A  B  A  B  B  B  A   A   A   C   C   A   B   A   C   C   A   C   C   C   B   A
#5  B  B  A  A  A  A  C  A  B   B   A   B   B   A   C   A   A   A   C   A   A   C   B   C
#6  C  A  C  C  A  B  B  C  C   C   B   C   A   B   B   B   B   B   A   C   A   A   B   A
#> dim(DF)
#[1] 34000    24

DF_ls <- sapply(seq(1, ncol(DF), 3), function(x) DF[,x:(x+2)], simplify = F)

system.time(
DF.res <- do.call(cbind,
       lapply(DF_ls, function(df.) { t(apply(df., 1, 
          function(x) { table(factor(unlist(x), levels = c("A", "B", "C"))) })) })))
#user  system elapsed 
#59.84    0.07   60.73 

#> head(DF.res)
#     A B C A B C A B C A B C A B C A B C A B C A B C
#[1,] 0 1 2 1 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 2 0 2 1 0 2 1 0 1 2 0 2 1
#[2,] 0 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0 2 0 1 0 3 0 1 1 1
#[3,] 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 0 2 3 0 0 1 2 0 2 0 1 1 2 0 0 0 3
#[4,] 1 0 2 1 2 0 1 2 0 2 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 2 1 0 2 1 1 1
#[5,] 1 2 0 3 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 0 1 1 1 3 0 0 2 0 1 0 1 2
#[6,] 1 0 2 1 1 1 0 1 2 0 1 2 1 2 0 0 3 0 2 0 1 2 1 0
```

**EDIT** Some more comments on the approach.

I'll do the above step by step.

The first step is to subset the different dataframes that are bound together; each one of those dataframes is put in a list. The function `function(x) { df.test[,x:(x+2)], simplify = F }` subsets the whole dataframe based on those values of `x`: `seq(1, ncol(df.test), 3)`. Extending this, if your different dataframes where 4 columns distant, `3` would have been changed with `4` in the above sequence.

```
#> df_ls <- sapply(seq(1, ncol(df.test), 3), function(x) df.test[,x:(x+2)], simplify = F)
#> df_ls
#[[1]]
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  A  B  C
#2  C  C  C
#3  A  B  B

#[[2]]
#  V4 V5 V6
#1  B  A  A
#2  C  C  C
#3  A  A  A
```

The next step is to `lapply` to the -previously made- list a function that counts each category in each row of one dataframe (i.e. element of the list). The function is this: `t(apply(df., 1, function(x) { table(factor(unlist(x), levels = c("A", "B", "C"))) }))`. The inside function (`function(x)`) turns *one* row in a factor with `levels` all the categories and counts (`table`) the number each category occured in that row. `apply` applies this function to each row (`MARGIN = 1`) of the dataframe. So, now, we have counted the frequency of each category in each row of *one* dataframe.

```
#> table(factor(unlist(df_ls[[1]][3,]), levels = c("A", "B", "C")))
     #df_ls[[1]][3,] is the third row of the first dataframe of df_ls 
                                  #(i.e. _one_ row of _one_ dataframe)
#A B C 
#1 2 0

#> apply(df_ls[[1]], 1, 
#+       function(x) { table(factor(unlist(x), levels = c("A", "B", "C"))) })
#  [,1] [,2] [,3]   #df_ls[[1]] is the first dataframe of df_ls (i.e. _one_ dataframe)
#A    1    0    1
#B    1    0    2
#C    1    3    0
```

Because, the return of `apply` is not in the wanted form we use `t` to swap rows with columns.

The next step, is to `lapply` all the above to each dataframe (i.e. element of the list).

```
#> lapply(df_ls, function(df.) { t(apply(df., 1, 
#+       function(x) { table(factor(unlist(x), levels = c("A", "B", "C"))) })) })
#[[1]]
#     A B C
#[1,] 1 1 1
#[2,] 0 0 3
#[3,] 1 2 0

#[[2]]
#     A B C
#[1,] 2 1 0
#[2,] 0 0 3
#[3,] 3 0 0
```

The last step is to `cbind` all those elements together. The way to bind by column all the elements of a list is to `do.call` `cbind` in that list.

```
#NOT the expected, using only cbind
#> cbind(lapply(df_ls, function(df.) { t(apply(df., 1, 
#+       function(x) { table(factor(unlist(x), levels = c("A", "B", "C"))) })) }))
#     [,1]     
#[1,] Integer,9
#[2,] Integer,9

#Correct!
#> do.call(cbind, lapply(df_ls, function(df.) { t(apply(df., 1, 
#+       function(x) { table(factor(unlist(x), levels = c("A", "B", "C"))) })) }))
#     A B C A B C
#[1,] 1 1 1 2 1 0
#[2,] 0 0 3 0 0 3
#[3,] 1 2 0 3 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you for answering another one of my questions alexis! Your solution is MUCH faster than the loop by orders of magnitude. I understand what table(factor(unlist)) does, but could you briefly explain do.call(cbind, lapply & t(apply)? do.call and apply are new to me. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Stefan: You're welcome! I, also, updated my answer. See if this commenting helps.

Comment: I carefully went through each step to make sure I understand - your comments were extremely helpful, and I get it all! Very clever; thank you so much for introducing me to the apply family!!

Comment: For reasons that are entirely unclear to me, I now get an error message on this code!? I even copy-paste verbatim from your DF example. Any idea why I see this when I run the last apply command: Error in apply(df., 1, function(x) { : dim(X) must have a positive length? Appears to be workspace specific but I cannot find the object that's at fault...

Comment: @Stefan: I can't replicate this error with the code in the answer. I did replicate it, though, using `DF_ls <- vector("list", 5)` (i.e. a list of `NULL`s). When I ran the `do.call .. apply etc`, I got the same error as you. Are you sure, all objects are assigned correctly? What does `str(DF_ls)` outputs?

Comment: In a clean workspace, I get this (only first one shown) from `str(DF_ls)` `List of 8
 $ :'data.frame': 34000 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ X1: chr [1:34000] "A" "B" "C" "C" ...
  ..$ X2: chr [1:34000] "C" "B" "B" "A" ...
  ..$ X3: chr [1:34000] "A" "A" "A" "B" ...` and all of the subsequent lapply code works fine.

Comment: But in my current workspace, I get this (only first and last 4 lines shown): `> str(DF_ls)
List of 24
 $ : chr [1:34000] "A" "A" "C" "A" ...
 $ : chr [1:34000] "C" "A" "C" "C" ...
 $ : chr [1:34000] "B" "C" "A" "C" ...` and `- attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 3 8
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "X1" "X2" "X3"
  ..$ : NULL`

Comment: Here the code fails. I must have changed some setting in my workspace or environment, but I'm unaware what it could be. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: In a clean workspace, the sapply statement makes DF_ls as such: `> summary(DF_ls)
     Length Class      Mode
[1,] 3      data.frame list
[2,] 3      data.frame list
[3,] 3      data.frame list
[4,] 3      data.frame list
[5,] 3      data.frame list
[6,] 3      data.frame list
[7,] 3      data.frame list
[8,] 3      data.frame list`

Comment: But in my current workspace, the sapply statement produces a DF_ls as such V3 to V8 omitted but identical: `> summary(DF_ls)
 V1.Length  V1.Class    V1.Mode  V2.Length  V2.Class    V2.Mode 
 34000      -none-     character 34000      -none-     character
 34000      -none-     character 34000      -none-     character
 34000      -none-     character 34000      -none-     character`

Comment: @Stefan: So, in your current workspace `DF_ls` is a 3 x 8 dataframe filled with `character, 34000`, I guess? `DF` is as it should be in your current workspace? I managed to re-make `DF_ls` in the correct form with: `temp <- do.call(cbind, DF_ls)` ; `DF_ls <- sapply(seq(1, ncol(temp), 3), function(x) temp[,x:(x+2)], simplify = F)` ; I hope this will be of use in your workspace, too. I can't understand, though, why this is happening.

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't fix it. I must have inadvertently changed something in my workspace or environment, because clearing it and starting fresh worked. Good practice to get into anyway. Hopefully it won't happen again. Thank you!